# How do I install SOX on UBuntu 11.0 with all format supported packages?

Tags: command-line, ubuntu-11.10, sox

I tried to install SOX ( Swiss Army knife of sound processing programs ) on Ubuntu 11.10. At first, I tried with apt-get install sox, it installed successfully but it couldn't convert wav to mp3. Then I installed libsox-fmt-mp3, so it started to convert mp3 to wav but still fails to convert wav to mp3. How do I install the packages for ubuntu 11.10 for all supported formats ?

P.S. I browsed SO for this and a question related with SOX was suggested to be moved here so I am directly posting here.

Comment: You are mistaken, this is off-topic here except in the unlikely case you need this in a professional server environment.

Comment: ...but it may be migrated to a better-suited site automatically through the vote to close mechanism, so don't repost the question somewhere else. Let it be migrated.

Answer (score 2):

Simplest way in ubuntu would be to run these two commands

`sudo apt-get install libasound2-plugins libasound2-python libsox-fmt-all`

`sudo apt-get install sox`

If you are in some other Linux, like CentOS or you need support for Vorbis and Ogg, you will have to compile from source, found by following this [Guide](http://quadloops.com/blog/installing-sox-in-ubuntu-12-04-and-working-with-ogg-and-vorbis-formats/)